# Name for the set Displacement, Velocity, Acceleration, etc

Tags: kinematics, terminology, differentiation, displacement, jerk

Is there a name for the set Displacement, Velocity, Acceleration, Jerk, etc?

The only name I can think of is 'Derivatives of displacement (wrt time)' which is rather long.

Comment: I think that is kinematic

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! If you can, using math notation should be shortest possible description, something like $x^{(n)}$ or $d^nx/dt^n$. Other than that I can also only thing of longish names. But at any rate, that's not really a conceptual physics question.